How do I avoid error "Request to run job refused because the job is already running" if no job is shown as "running" when I start a chosen step?
I cannot start the SQLServer Agent job even though nothing is shown as running.
Background: I messed it up and forgot about it afterwards
I had only one step in my test job and added one other step. My aim was to start from step 2 only since I wanted to run only step 2, not the quite long-running step 1. When I chose to "start from step", it just began running without showing me the choice of steps, and when I looked at the job, it still had only one step, and the long-running step was running.
My first guess is that I must have missed adding the second step by closing the menu without saving. My second guess it that I just closed the window with the green "Running", thinking that this might stop the job, but I know from later checks that closing is not stopping. I then forgot about it during some other work.
Since I later could not see any box that said "Running", I added the second step again and started from that step 2, and then, the error in question came up.

The error:


Start failed for Job ..
...
SQLServer Agent Error: Request to run job .. (from User ..) refused because the job is already running from a request by User .. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 22022)

Clearly, the long-running step 1 was still running in the backround. But I did not know this anymore.
Therefore I asked the question:
How do I avoid error "Request to run job refused because the job is already running" if no job is shown as "running" when I start a chosen step?

See this on Meta at Question with a clear error message and an easy fix that was closed as "too localized", likely "not relevant to most of our audience". Reopen or Move?

It would not make sense to wait this out. There was no menu showing something as running, but I still clicked to stop the job:

Stopping the job even if you do not see that it runs showed me:

This green success message proves that the job indeed ran in the background without showing any signs of life in the frontend. I must have closed the window and then, I must have forgotten about it.
I checked stopping a job that does not run, it fails:

I guess that you could check and fix such things also with some command prompt tricks, there might be a job that you can see and kill or stop, but I did not give it a try.
After stopping, the step can be run again:

